# Check Credit Card Type (Mastercard vs Visa) using PayPal API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

Are there any API that I can check if my customer are using paying using Mastercard or Visa card?

Just the card type is enough, no need the number.

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210298/check-credit-card-type-mastercard-vs-visa-using-paypal-api#comment99047801_56210662) below, we don't have access to user credit card as they are stored in PayPal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter to you? Is this to present a "you paid with card x" in your interface? If so, just show "you paid with your paypal <email address>". That's likely to be just as useful to the user.

Answer (score 4):

PayPal keeps buyer billing information private by design -- so, for normal PayPal payments, the receiving account will have no indication whether it was paid with e.g.:

- Their existing PayPal balance
- PayPal Credit
- A local bank account
- Visa
- MasterCard
- American Express
- Discover
- Some other local card or funding source specific to the buyer's country

This is said to be a privacy and security feature: if one of the many sites that accepts PayPal is ever compromised, no information about customers' financials or funding sources will be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, you could use the Vault API for saving the credit card securely and use it for paypal payments. Since PayPal acquired BrainTree the product for handling credit cards directly is deprecated and replaced with [BrainTree Direct](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct).

If you are only handling PayPal payments directly there are no options to view the payment method.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it in 2020? Using Vault v2 with Orders + Payments v2?